# How can I get every element except the last one with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have several divs

```
<div class="myClass"></div>
<div class="myClass"></div>
<div class="myClass"></div>
<div class="myClass"></div>
```

that are being generated dynamically. When the button is clicked, I need to remove all divs with myClass class except the last one. So far I have tried some variations of:

```
$('.myClass').not($('.myClass').last()).remove();
```

OR

```
$('.myClass').not($(this).last()).remove();
```

neither seem to work.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your first example works.http://jsfiddle.net/4mzqbfh3/

Comment: I don't know why it didn't work. Maybe something was blocking it. potatopeelings' solution worked for me. Thank you too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this way:

```
 $('.myClass:not(:last)').remove();
```

Answer (score 2):

your code is running fine with no problems

You need to put it in `$(document).ready();`

here is demo
https://jsfiddle.net/8w2jb1Lr/

Comment: I don't know why it didn't work. Maybe something was blocking it. potatopeelings' solution worked for me. Thank you too.